# How could I make this hard code into a while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, hardcode

So basically I'm trying to make this matrix (with a 2d array) in the format

```
1 

1 1
1 1

1 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 1

1 1 1 1
1 2 2 1
1 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 

1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

depending on what size the user inputs. I can do this with hard code as shown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int userSize;


    do {
        cin >> userSize;
        int userArray[userSize][userSize];
        int size = 1;
        int maxSize = 99;

        for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < userSize; j++) {

                if ((j > 2 && j < userSize - 3) &&
                   (i > 2 && i < userSize - 3)){
                    userArray[i][j] = size + 3;
                }



                if ((j > 1 && j < userSize - 2) &&
                (i > 1 && i < userSize - 2)) {
                    userArray[i][j] = size + 2;
                }


                else if ((j > 0 && j < userSize - 1) &&
                    (i > 0 && i < userSize - 1)) {

                    userArray[i][j] = size + 1;
                }

                else {
                    userArray[i][j] = size;
                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < userSize; j++) {
                cout << setw(3) << userArray[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;


    }while(userSize != 0);



    return 0;
}
```

however I need to be able to do this up to 99, which would obviously be a lot to write. Is there a way I can do this with a while loop instead? Below is my failed attempt that only outputs garbage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int userSize;
    int maxSize = 99;
    int size = 1;

    do {
        cin >> userSize;

        int myMatrix[userSize][userSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < userSize; j++) {

                while (maxSize >= 0) {

                    if ((j > maxSize) && (j < userSize - (maxSize + 1)) &&
                        ((i > maxSize) && (i < userSize - (maxSize + 1)))) {
                            myMatrix[i][j] = size + maxSize;
                        }

                    /*
                    if ((j > 1 && j < userSize - 2) &&
                    (i > 1 && i < userSize - 2)) {
                        myMatrix[i][j] = size + 2;
                    }


                    else if ((j > 0 && j < userSize - 1) &&
                        (i > 0 && i < userSize - 1)) {

                        myMatrix[i][j] = size + 1;
                    }
                    */

                    else {
                        myMatrix[i][j] = size;
                     }



                    maxSize = maxSize - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < userSize; j++) {
                cout << setw(3) << myMatrix[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }while(userSize != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "...depending on what size the user inputs." In what way does the matrix you output depend on the user's input? It's not clear.

Comment: @John sorry about that I added the full code for the original to show how it works

Comment: If it's not too much trouble can you explain how it works? Is the output always a square matrix, and the user inputs the dimension of that square matrix?

Comment: It only needs three loops: one for the horizontal, one for the vertical and one for the numeric increment.  I'll make an answer.

Comment: Doesn't even need a numeric increment loop. The value at a given cell is a function of the matrix dimension, N, the current row, and the current column.

Comment: Does it HAVE TO BE a while loop? This would be more natural to me as two nested for loops.

Comment: @John Yea exactly so the user inputs a number from 1-99 and that number determines the dimension of the square matrix. I showed examples of what the outputted matrix above looks like for inputs 1-5. The program keeps going until the user inputs 0.

Comment: Your second example (for input 2) is wrong, then.

Comment: @John you're right, sorry about that I fixed it. Also, no it doesn't have to be a while loop. Also I'm not sure what you mean about the value at a given cell. How does it relate to the column, row, and dimensions?

Comment: When I say "cell", I mean the location designated by the unique (row, column) pair. The 2x2 matrix has 4 cells. The 3x3 matrix has 9 cells. The value in each of these can be determined mathematically depending on its row, column, and matrix dimension.

Comment: @John Well yea, but how so? Do you mean without using a while loop? Because I think I did what you said when I hard coded it, but I was looking for a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah What do you mean by the numeric increment loop?

Comment: Chase gives an example of how to calculate the value of a cell in his answer. You should read that, see if it fits your needs, and accept it if it does.

Comment: Sorry @John was right.  Nested for loops and a minmax test are all that is needed: https://onlinegdb.com/SyrZ9TpHI   Even so if you could turn the pseudo code in the answer below into real code it would be way better than what I did.

Comment: The answer below is really simple: https://onlinegdb.com/B1vm0Tar8  I wish i had thought of that...

Answer (score 3):

looks to me like you want the minimum steps from an outer edge. Here is some psuedo-code

```
int[,] ComputeMatrix(int m,int n)
{
     int[,] matrix = new int[m,n]
     for(int i = 0;i < m;i++)
     for(int j = 0;j < n;j++)
     {
          //Minimum distance from each of the 4 walls
          matrix[i,j] = 1 + Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(i,j),m-i-1),n-j-1);
     }

      return matrix;
}
```

Comment: It looks like valid C#, but it's also serves very nicely as pseudocode as Chase stated.